# how to get updatedDateTime property in response for listChannels api in ms graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, webhooks

How can I obtain the "updated time" property for a list of channels in a team when using the Microsoft Graph API? Currently, I am only receiving the "created time" property in the response, but I need the "updated time" for polling purposes. Is there a specific query parameter I need to include in my request to receive this property in the response?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels?$filter=id eq '19:xxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2'
```

i have already tried using webhook for change notifications but i am getting notification for every created/updated at same time. It is a known issue [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#update-notifications-occur-on-creation-and-soft-deletion-of-users). So i need updatedtime somehow, then i can poll the updated channel data only by filtering that using updated date.

Comment: According to the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties the channel resource doesn't have "updated time" property

Comment: yeah i think there is no way to find out updatedDate/Time

Answer (score 0):

cannot check if it works, as i don't have api permissions for channels in my org, but try to include `expand=teamsAsyncOperation` in the request to check if this works for you

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels?$filter=id eq '19:xxxxxxxxxxx@thread.tacv2'&expand=teamsAsyncOperation
```

Response should include `teamsAsyncOperation` [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsasyncoperation?view=graph-rest-1.0) object linked to channel, which property `createdDateTime`(of [operation type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsasyncoperationtype?view=graph-rest-1.0)) or `lastActionDateTime` – might serve to your purpose. channel resource itself doesn't seem to have "updated time" property according to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: thanks @kadis for your help, i tried with `teamsyncOperation` but unfortunately it giving me the same response as before